# Unable to take copy of an array returns Type' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

Interface:

```
export interface IClient {
  client_name: string
  client_id?: string
}
```

Reducer

```
export interface ClientState {
    client_name: IClient[]
}

export const clientInitialState: ClientState = {
    client_name: null
}


export const clientReducer = createReducer(
    clientInitialState,
    on(ClientActionTypes.addClientSuccess,(state, {client_name}) => {
      const item = [...client_name]
      return {
        ...state,
        newItem

      }
    }
  ))
```

With the above code I'm trying to append values inside array like ["Item1", "Item2"] but I get the error "Type' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator." The error comes in the [...client_name] spread operator. I need help in fixing this or any other way to append. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the initial value of `clientInitialState.client_name` is `null`.
Trying to spread null will give you that error:

```js
const foo = null;
const bar = [...foo]; // object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

You could initialize your variable with `[]`:

```js
const foo = [];
const bar = [...foo]; // No error!
```

Comment: Thanks, but still get the same error, I have added the screenshot after your update

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
export const clientReducer = createReducer(
    clientInitialState,
    on(ClientActionTypes.addClientSuccess,(state, {client_name}) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        newItem: [...state.client_name, ...client_name]
      }
    }
  ))
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and I get error like state.client_name is not iterable and for "...client_name" "Type' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator." I have also added the interface for IClient in the question

Comment: I think it because your data is not an array check both state.client_name and client_name